# How to set an element at Row index and a column index in order to create a sparse matrix using linked list

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

I want to create a sparse matrix using linked lists in java. A node is sorted based on the row and column index. I managed to create a sparse vector but for some reason, I can't figure out how to do it using two indices.

The constructor

```
public LLSparseM(int nr, int nc) {
        numeberOfColums = nc;
        numerOfRows = nr;
        head = new node(-1, -1, 0, null, null);
        tail = new node(nr, nc, 0, head, null);
        head.setNext(tail);
        return;
    }
```

The set element method

```
public void setElement(int ridx, int cidx, int val) {
    if (head.getNext().getElement() == 0) {
        node newnode = new node(ridx, cidx, val, head, tail);
        head.setNext(newnode);
        tail.setPrev(newnode);
    } else {
        node current = head.getNext();
        while (current.getRidx() < ridx || (current.getRidx() <= ridx && current.getCidx() < cidx)) {
            current = current.getNext();
        }
        if (current.getRidx() == ridx && current.getCidx() == cidx) {
            node newest = new node(ridx, cidx, val, current.getPrev(), current.getNext());
            current.getPrev().setNext(newest);
            current.getNext().setPrev(newest);
        } else if (current.getRidx() > ridx || current.getRidx() >= ridx && current.getCidx() > current.getCidx()) {
            if (head.getRidx() > ridx || head.getRidx() == ridx && head.getCidx() > cidx) {
                node newest = new node(ridx, cidx, val, null, head);
                tail = head;
                head.setPrev(newest);
                head = newest;
                tail.setNext(null);
            } else {
                node temp = current.getPrev();
                node newest = new node(ridx, cidx, val, temp, current);
                temp.setNext(newest);
                current.setPrev(newest);
            }

        } else if (current.getRidx() == numerOfRows && current.getCidx() == numeberOfColums) {
            node newest = new node(ridx, cidx, val, tail.getPrev(), tail);
            tail.getPrev().setNext(newest);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you single-stepped your code in the debugger to see where it's going wrong?